# Trying to set textview in toolbar to singleline in android

Tags: android, android-toolbar

I am trying set textview in toolbar to singleline but the text coming up over the icons that are placed in the toolbar this happening even after adding singleline and Ellipsize. I am not getting three dots.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    local:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/relativeLayoutID"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/toolbar_title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_gravity="left"
            android:text="Welcome back!"
            android:textColor="@color/whiteText"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_large" />

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/spinner"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:spinnerMode="dropdown"
            style="@style/MyDarkToolbarStyle"
            android:visibility="gone" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/keyIcon"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_gravity="right|center"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/alert"
            android:contentDescription="@string/logo"
            android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
            android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
            android:src="@drawable/key" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/alert"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_gravity="right|center"
            android:contentDescription="@string/logo"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/home"
            android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
            android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
            android:src="@drawable/bell" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/home"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_gravity="right|center"
            android:contentDescription="@string/logo"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/logo"
            android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
            android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
            android:src="@drawable/tool" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/logo"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_gravity="right|center"
            android:contentDescription="@string/logo"
            android:paddingRight="5dp"
            android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
            android:src="@drawable/rupees" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

I am not sure why this happening?

Comment: toolbar_title has layout_width="wrap_content" .. (fixed width may be needed)

Comment: I know that solves the issues but why this happening? In other layout when I using the same configuration in listview the three dots are coming up properly.

Comment: If you are using a tool bar you need to specify your icons in main/menu.xml layout. not anywhere else you need to call onOptionMenuCreated method like that... No need to give title in toolbar... Its automatically taken from appName

Comment: My Ui design require me to do this way. Also why I show them on menu.xml automatically the three dots come up and images are inside the three dots which I don't want to show that way... anyways How do I disable three dots in the right corner? Is this possible in all the versions?

Comment: @TheDevMan To remove the overflow menu dots you need to remove the settings part from menu.xml file. Those three dots will vanish.

Comment: I tried that lot of times didn't work for me.